# OR clause takes longer time

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query as an example below, but its running forever .. If I do union then I have copy entire large query .. Any help on this fix

```
select columns 
 from table a
 join (select *
         from ( select *, row_number() over( partition BY id ORDER BY date ) row_seq
                  from table b
              ) where row_seq = 1
       ) o ON  a.id = o.id OR  a.id = o.src_id 
 left join table p  on a.partner_c = p.id
 left join table pp on a.parnt_id = pp.id
```

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.

Comment: The value is present either in id column or src_id of table b and that value is present in the table a ..

Comment: Yeah, that's gonna slow it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner part

```
select *
from ( 
    select *,
        row_number() over( partition BY id ORDER BY date ) row_seq
    from table b
) where row_seq = 1
```

can be written using the [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) clause like so:

```
select *,
from table b
qualify row_number() over( partition BY id ORDER BY date ) = 1
```

which can be pushed into a CTE like:

```
WITH raw_rows AS (
    select *,
    from table b
    qualify row_number() over( partition BY id ORDER BY date ) = 1
) 
select columns 
from table a
join raw_rows o ON (a.id = o.id OR  a.id = o.src_id)
left join table p  on a.partner_c = p.id
left join table pp on a.parnt_id = pp.id
```

which means you can union that whole thing or just the `table a`  and `raw_rows o`

```
WITH raw_rows AS (
    select *,
    from table b
    qualify row_number() over( partition BY id ORDER BY date ) = 1
), a_and_o AS (
    select a.columns
        ,o.columns 
    from table a
    join raw_rows o ON a.id = o.id 

    UNION ALL

    select a.columns
        ,o.columns 
    from table a
    join raw_rows o ON a.id = o.src_id
)    
select columns 
from a_and_o a
left join table p  on a.partner_c = p.id
left join table pp on a.parnt_id = pp.id
```

but this will give you a slightly different result if `o.src_id == o.id`  for any row, as it will match both verse the OR vesion will have those lines once. You can pay the GROUP BY cost by swapping to UNION to de-dup, but then if you have many lines you want to keep those will be lost. Or you can change second half of the union to not included those line with

```
join raw_rows o ON a.id = o.src_id AND o.src_id != o.id
```

depends on your data and needs.

Comment: Thank you showing the use of `qualify` and including a thorough explanation!

Comment: Thanks, Simeon, I have used union but the problem is entire query needs to repeated hence I was looking to avoid repeating twice.. I have tried CTE but that too was taking long time

Comment: The CTE with the OR option is equal to the sub-select , so would be "as bad", but the concept of using a CTE is you select all the stuff you want "written once" in the CTE and the pull from the CTE twice.. because then it is a Common Table Expression. Looking how your example is written the two LEFT joins should have nothing to do with the A and O tables.

Comment: Thank you Simeon , I can only do via Union logic